# Shift key, arrow keys and alt keys not working due to incorrect keymap

Tags: keyboard

I can open XKeyCaps to change the mapping. It looks like I am on the standard 105 key xfree86 us keyboard.

I have a HP Probook 450 g4 laptop. If anyone knows the correct keyboard layout, or how I can find it, that would be fantastic.

Comment: Providing your OS/release details (ie. details of your software stack) would be helpful

Comment: 22.04 running xfce and the latest updates

Comment: So not Xubuntu 22.04 LTS, are you sure you've added all of the required Xfce packages?

Comment: I just checked with tasksel and it seems I have all the required packages. It was working before and the issue seems to be very intermittent.